# python regex - Dashes match as digits when using re.IGNORECASE

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a regular expression for stripping non-numeric characters from 13-digit ISBNs, and I came across some weird behavior that I'd like to understand.  I tested this with Python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2:

```
import re
re.sub("\D", '', '978-1-936978-09-0')
```

This gives 9781936978090, correctly.  But I noticed that if I do this...

```
re.sub("\D", '', '978-1-936978-09-0', re.IGNORECASE)
```

...with re.IGNORECASE, it *leaves in the last two dashes*, giving this: 9781936978-09-0.

Not that it should matter, but I double-checked that all four dashes are the exact same character (just a normal dash).  I tried some variants (like [^\d] instead of \D, or [^0-9]) and got the same weird result.

This isn't urgent for me, since ignoring case doesn't matter for this, but I'd like to know what's going on.  Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly enough, `re.sub(re.compile("\D", re.IGNORECASE), '', '978-1-936978-09-0')` gives the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth parameter of [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is not `flags`, but replace count. You should specify `flags` using `flags` keyword argument.

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
#                             ^^^^^^^
```

---

```
>>> re.sub("\D", '', '978-1-936978-09-0', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'9781936978090'
```

Comment: Ah, of course!  And re.IGNORECASE is actually the value 2, so I'm just setting the count to 2.  Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that `re.IGNORECASE == 2` so it only replaces the first 2 occurences of `"\D"`. Also, one would better use `r"\D"` as `pattern` although it doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 2):

Because of a python `re` "bug" your `re.IGNORECASE` is not used as flag in `re.sub` -> it's the count.
Instead it's used for the `count` parameter.

To avoid this name the parameter and it will work.

Example:

```
re.sub("\D", '', '978-1-936978-09-0', re.IGNORECASE)
9781936978-09-0

re.sub("\D", '', '978-1-936978-09-0', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
9781936978090
```

Tested in python 3.2.0 and 3.3.0

Comment: technically this is not a bug, it's an inconsistency of the API which can lead to confusion, but a bug is something different.

Comment: Because of this i wrote "bug" instead of bug. I know it's not a real bug but it confuses some people from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong parameter, `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`. Fourth is `count`. It is very easy to fall for this pitfall if you test your regular expression using `re.search` before using it for replacements.